# Running topology from supervisor node

Tags: java, nimbus

Can I run a topology form a supervisor node ? because when I try it  it gives me the current error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Any help please ? 
Best regards .